# How to properly re-write AngularJS code to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs

I have the code below which reads stores and updates data  to and from from localstorage and it works fine with AngularJS.

**Here is my issue:**
Am trying to re-write the Angularjs code  to React but it throws error unexpected token.

AngularJS:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    
     //called at initiazation, reads from localstorage if array is present there
      $scope.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage = function() {
        var readArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('messagingArray');
        if (readArrayStr && readArrayStr.length > 0) {
          $scope.arr = JSON.parse(readArrayStr);
        } else {
          $scope.arr = [{
              name: "user1"
            },
            {
              name: "user2"
            },
            {
              name: "user3"
            },
            {
              name: "user4"
            }
          ];
        }
      }
    
      //called at each update, stores the latest status in localstorage
      $scope.updateLocalStorage = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('messagingArray', JSON.stringify($scope.arr));
        /* console.log("updated local storage !!"); */
      }
    
      $scope.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage();
    
    
    });
</script>
```

React:

```
    <script src="react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="browser.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="app"></div>

    
<script type="text/babel">


class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 
 //called at initiazation, reads from localstorage if array is present there
  //const checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage () {
const checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage = () => {
    var readArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('messagingArray');
    if (readArrayStr && readArrayStr.length > 0) {
      this.state.arr = JSON.parse(readArrayStr);
    } else {


this.state = {
      arr: [
    {      name: "user1"},
    {      name: "user2"},
    {      name: "user3"},
    {      name: "user4"}
      ],

    };

    }
   }

this.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage = this.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage.bind(this);
this.updateLocalStorage = this.updateLocalStorage.bind(this);
  }


  //called at each update, stores the latest status in localstorage
updateLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('messagingArray', JSON.stringify(this.state.arr));
   
  };


componentDidMount() {
this.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage(); 
this.updateLocalStorage();
}
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h3>Display Data</h3>
 <ul>
            {this.state.arr.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.name}
               
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
</div>

    );
  }
}




ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));



</script>
```

**Here is the updated react error message:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
    at new Application (eval at transform.run
```

Comment: Could you share exact error message?

Comment: @agulowaty I have updated the post to add error message

Comment: Are you able to run React in dev mode and grab errors there? What you pasted is the minfied/santised version of the code.

Comment: @agulowaty I haved updatedthe reactjs code and the new error messages that it shows.

Comment: Your `Application`'s constructor is not properly closed, it's missing the closing curly brace

Comment: @thomaux I have checked and my constructor properly closed. what could be the best place to put function `checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage() {`  since its the one causing the error.

Comment: You are missing the `function` keyword infront of the definition of `checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage() {...}`. And please consider formatting your code for better readability when posting code.

Comment: @Martin
if i create function as per below
`checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage = () => {`
It throw error

**checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage is not defined**

Comment: Missing the `const` keyword. Try `const checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage = () => {...}` and it should work.

Comment: @Martin
when I add const, it throw error.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
    at new Application (eval at transform.run`  I have updated the code to reflect changes so far.

Comment: move the definition of `checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage` outside of the constructor, like you did with `updateLocalStorage`

Comment: @Martin Moving the definition of   `checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage` outside of the constructor solve the problem. You can update your answer so that I can accept it as the answer

Comment: Glad we solved it. But the question really is so specific to your own code and use-case that I don't think it will ever be of any use to anybody else; therefore I think it not useful to post an answer and would prefer that the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by Moving the definition of **checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage** outside of the constructor.

**Here is the code below**

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 



this.state = {
      arr: [
    {      name: "user1"},
    {      name: "user2"},
    {      name: "user3"},
    {      name: "user4"}
      ],

    };



this.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage = this.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage.bind(this);
this.updateLocalStorage = this.updateLocalStorage.bind(this);
  }

checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage () {
//const checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage = () => {
    var readArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('messagingArray');
    if (readArrayStr && readArrayStr.length > 0) {
      this.state.arr = JSON.parse(readArrayStr);
    } else {
this.state.arr;

}
}
  //called at each update, stores the latest status in localstorage
updateLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('messagingArray', JSON.stringify(this.state.arr));
   
  };


componentDidMount() {
this.checkAndInitiateFromLocalStorage(); 
this.updateLocalStorage();
}
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h3>Display Data</h3>
 <ul>
            {this.state.arr.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.name}
               
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
</div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```